# Spring / Hibernate project with Tomcat and JQuery

Tags: jquery, eclipse, hibernate, spring, tomcat

I have a Dynamic Web Project that implements Spring and Hibernate using a Tomcat Server (v6). I'm lauching Tomcat with my Eclipse Galileo and I'm not getting any errors in the console but Tomcat is rendering my webpages randomly.

The page just keep loading but without displaying anything, there's nothing on the console either. When I go in debug mode, it goes throught the right steps, everything seems alright.

What am I not getting here? Plus when I stop Tomcat, it renders a part of the page. I'm wondering if JQuery could be the problem?

The thing is that it's a collaborative project and that the others managed to run the web application in the most alright way.

Please, share your experience with me.

Comment: If "view source" is indeed showing you the proper code, try another browser and see if your page renders there.

Comment: Actually, no it's not showing the proper code. My mistake, it was the code that was rendered when stopping tomcat.

New ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't be a jQuery issue, especially if the standard approach of placing jQuery code in `$(document).ready()` is utilized. The DOM will load before jQuery runs.

Answer (score 0):

You mention it is happening in debug mode. Maybe an obvious suggestion but are you sure you have no breakpoints in the code that might be suspending some tomcat threads?

Comment: No I don't have any breakpoint and it does the same thing when I'm not on debug mode.

The webapp does work for a few minutes sometimes.